# Universal app splash screen errors

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode4

I have created a universal app in x code 4 and am attempting to use their "launch images".  I am however running into an issue where once the iPad splash screen displays it will flash to the iPhone splash screen quickly before going into the application.  Has anyone else run into this and is there a fix?
Thanks!

Comment: Refer the following link to ensure you are doing as per the apple's recommendations. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

Comment: Thanks Pratiksha, but that was information for icons.  I'm looking for splash screens and I was very careful to make them the right sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this on a universal app, but it was because I implemented a custom fade sequence that referenced the iPhone default.png during launch (even on an iPad). Once I figured that out, I just set a check for whether the device was an iPad, and if so, disabled the fade call. Do you reference the file in any way aside from the typical launch?